# How to parse unix timestamp to time.Time

Tags: go, time, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to parse an Unix [timestamp](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) but I get out of range error. That doesn't really makes sense to me, because the layout is correct (as in the Go docs):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    tm, err := time.Parse("1136239445", "1405544146")
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(tm)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lFxVml0qH4)

Answer (score 404, accepted):

The `time.Parse` function does not do Unix timestamps. Instead you can use `strconv.ParseInt` to parse the string to `int64` and create the timestamp with `time.Unix`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt("1405544146", 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tm := time.Unix(i, 0)
    fmt.Println(tm)
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-07-16 20:55:46 +0000 UTC
```

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/v_j6UIro7a

**Edit:**

Changed from `strconv.Atoi` to `strconv.ParseInt` to avoid int overflows on 32 bit systems.

Comment: Any idea why there is no such reference in the docs? They even give the unix timestap layout as a layout example.

Comment: I guess it is because a unix timestamp isn't requiring parsing as it is not a text representation, but rather an integer representation of time. You just happened to have a string representation of an integer value. And the mentioning of 1136239445 in the docs is probably just to clarify what exact timestamp is to be used as reference time, not that it is to be used as layout.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `strconv.ParseUint` instead as negative numbers don't make sense anyway?

Comment: @Atmocreations: `func Unix(sec int64, nsec int64) Time` receives `int64` values. Also, negative numbers for sec makes perfect sense - they describe dates prior to 1970! :) As for `nsec`, negative values means to remove that many nanoseconds from the seconds.

Comment: I want only the date and time as " 2014-07-16 20:55:46" how could be it achieved ?

Answer (score 34):

You can directly use time.Unix function of time which converts the unix time stamp to UTC

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)


func main() {
    unixTimeUTC:=time.Unix(1405544146, 0) //gives unix time stamp in utc 

    unitTimeInRFC3339 :=unixTimeUTC.Format(time.RFC3339) // converts utc time to RFC3339 format

    fmt.Println("unix time stamp in UTC :--->",unixTimeUTC)
    fmt.Println("unix time stamp in unitTimeInRFC3339 format :->",unitTimeInRFC3339)
}
```

Output

```
unix time stamp in UTC :---> 2014-07-16 20:55:46 +0000 UTC
unix time stamp in unitTimeInRFC3339 format :----> 2014-07-16T20:55:46Z
```

Check in Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/5FtRdnkxAd

Comment: `time.Unix()` is documented to return the local time. Therefore, the `unixTimeUTC` in this answer is not always providing the time in the UTC timezone. Only when the local time zone corresponds to UTC.

Comment: @Dr.Jan-PhilipGehrcke: I wonder whether it ultimately matters. `time.Unix()` will parse the time into a time in some timezone (with the timezone information). It can then be reused anywhere (for instance converting to a given TZ). True, the variable name may not be fortunate in that case.

Answer (score 6):

Sharing a few functions which I created for dates:

Please note that I wanted to get time for a particular location (not just UTC time). If you want UTC time, just remove loc variable and .In(loc) function call.

```
func GetTimeStamp() string {
     loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
     t := time.Now().In(loc)
     return t.Format("20060102150405")
}
func GetTodaysDate() string {
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
    current_time := time.Now().In(loc)
    return current_time.Format("2006-01-02")
}

func GetTodaysDateTime() string {
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
    current_time := time.Now().In(loc)
    return current_time.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
}

func GetTodaysDateTimeFormatted() string {
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")
    current_time := time.Now().In(loc)
    return current_time.Format("Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04 PM")
}

func GetTimeStampFromDate(dtformat string) string {
    form := "Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04 PM"
    t2, _ := time.Parse(form, dtformat)
    return t2.Format("20060102150405")
}
```

Comment: Removing `.In(loc)` gave me time in `-0400 EDT`. Replacing it with `.In(time.UTC)` gave me time in UTC.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but I noticed that a practical answer is missing.

For example, we were working with the MavLink protocol and we need to process a message with a [structure defined here](https://mavlink.io/en/messages/common.html#SCALED_PRESSURE).

If we have this data structure:

| Field Name | Type | Units | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| time_boot_ms | uint64_t | ms | Timestamp (time since system boot). |
| press_abs | float | hPa | Absolute pressure |
| press_diff | float | hPa | Differential pressure 1 |
| temperature | int16_t | cdegC | Absolute pressure temperature |
| temperature_press_diff ** | int16_t | cdegC | Differential pressure temperature (0, if not available). Report values of 0 (or 1) as 1 cdegC. |

So, we receive constant updates that we need to process using the `time_boot_ms` as reference to insert them on the database and synchronize them with other messages.

#### What can we do?

As we noticed, the time is in milliseconds and everyone, that has some experience with *Go*, knows that for some unknown reason it's just way too complex to convert a millisecond resolution Unix `timestamp` to `time.Time`. The built-in `time.Unix()` function only supports second and nanosecond precision.

#### How we can get millisecond precision?

Well, we might wait until they release the version `1.7` of **Go** or we either have to multiply the milliseconds to nanoseconds or split them into seconds and nanoseconds.

Lets implement the second idea, spit the into seconds and nanoseconds:

```golang
unixUTCtime := time.Unix(ms/int64(1000), (ms%int64(1000))*int64(1000000))
```

Now we can encapsulate it in a `func` and use it in our main like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const msInSecond int64 = 1e3
const nsInMillisecond int64 = 1e6

// UnixToMS Converts Unix Epoch from milliseconds to time.Time
func UnixToMS (ms int64) time.Time {
    return time.Unix(ms/msInSecond, (ms%msInSecond)*nsInMillisecond)
}


func main() {
    unixTimes := [...]int64{758991688, 758992188, 758992690, 758993186}
    var unixUTCTimes []time.Time
    for index, unixTime := range unixTimes {
        unixUTCTimes = append(unixUTCTimes, UnixToMS(unixTime))
        if index > 0 {
            timeDifference := unixUTCTimes[index].Sub(unixUTCTimes[index-1])
            fmt.Println("Time difference in ms :--->", timeDifference)
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```bash
Time difference in ms :---> 500ms
Time difference in ms :---> 502ms
Time difference in ms :---> 496ms
```

[Check in Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vmfr6EdTi8A)

#### Update

From version `1.7`, `go` now provides millisecond resolution either to convert a unix time represented as a `int64` number into a Time type (nanosecond precision) using [time.UnixMilli](https://pkg.go.dev/time#UnixMilli) function or from Time into millisecond precision using [UnixMilli](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.UnixMilli) function. This is their implementation:

```golang
func Unix(sec int64, nsec int64) Time {
    if nsec < 0 || nsec >= 1e9 {
        n := nsec / 1e9
        sec += n
        nsec -= n * 1e9
        if nsec < 0 {
            nsec += 1e9
            sec--
        }
    }
    return unixTime(sec, int32(nsec))
}


func UnixMilli(msec int64) Time {
    return Unix(msec/1e3, (msec%1e3)*1e6)
}

func (t Time) UnixMilli() int64 {
    return t.unixSec()*1e3 + int64(t.nsec())/1e6
}
```

##### How to use this Teo?

Very simple just modify this line from the previous implementation of our example:

```golang
unixUTCTimes = append(unixUTCTimes, UnixToMS(unixTime))
```

with this code:

```golang
unixUTCTimes = append(unixUTCTimes, time.UnixMilli(unixTime))
```

No need of other functions just call `time.UnixMilli(unixTime)`. Check the [playground here](https://go.dev/play/p/rj0PLvgUp4l).

Answer (score 5):

for millis unix timestamp precision, in go1.18

```
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt("1652084489543", 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tm := time.UnixMilli(i)
    fmt.Println(tm)
```

Answer (score 3):

I do a lot of logging where the timestamps are float64 and use this function to get the timestamps as string:

```
func dateFormat(layout string, d float64) string{
    intTime := int64(d)
    t := time.Unix(intTime, 0)
    if layout == "" {
        layout = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
    }
    return t.Format(layout)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [go documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix), Unix returns a local time.

> Unix returns the local Time corresponding to the given Unix time

This means the output would depend on the machine your code runs on, which, most often is what you need, but sometimes, you may want to have the value in UTC.

To do so, I adapted the [snippet](https://play.golang.org/p/IC9rOLa0FRs) to make it return a time in UTC:

```
i, err := strconv.ParseInt("1405544146", 10, 64)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
tm := time.Unix(i, 0)
fmt.Println(tm.UTC())
```

This prints on my machine (in CEST)

```
2014-07-16 20:55:46 +0000 UTC
```