# Parsing javascript date to a golang date

Tags: javascript, datetime, go

I need to parse a JavaScript formatted date which I obtain from calling `new Date()` and looks like `Sat Aug 27 2016 17:07:43 GMT+1000 (AEST)`.

I am then posting this as a string go my golang server where I need to parse it to be formatted the same as when calling `time.Now()` which looks like `2016-08-30 14:05:31.563336601 +1000 AEST`.
This date is then stored in my database via gorm which is why I believe it needs to be in this format.

What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `+new Date()` to get a timestamp and feed that into something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987131/how-to-parse-unix-timestamp-in-golang

Comment: Hi @RobM. This is a good idea but after inserting it into the db it looks like this: `48624-10-12 20:40:21+11`

Comment: Did you try to use the javascript date method *toISOString()*? Maybe it format the date in the way you need. If you work on timestamps, pay attention that javascript produce the time in milliseconds, the c standard is in seconds (in golang Unix) and go lang support even nanoseconds. So you have to check which type of conversion you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you the correct date. Note how you specify the format:

```golang
jsTime, err := time.Parse("Mon Jan 02 2006 15:04:05 GMT-0700 (MST)", "Sat Aug 27 2016 17:07:43 GMT+1000 (AEST)")

if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Printf("Error %v\n", err)
    return
}

fmt.Println(jsTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000 -0700 MST"))
```

[Example](https://go.dev/play/p/AbuVIP5Wx0T)