# Go convert int64 (from UnixNano) to location time string

Tags: string, go, time

I have an int64 like:

> 1502712864232

Which is the result of a REST GET to a service. I can convert it to a string easily enough. It is a Unixnano timestamp.

What I really need is to convert it to a **string** which is related to a timezone like "Europe/London". Such as:-

> "14/08/2017, 13:14:24"

Such as produced by this handy utility:
http://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html

Would very much appreciate any assistance.

==> Update.

Thanks to @evanmcdonnal for such a useful answer. Much appreciated.
Turns out that the data I had was not UnixNano at all (sorry) it was milliseconds from Epoch. Source is a Jenkins timestamp....

So... I wrote the following helper function to get what I need:

```
// Arg 1 is an int64 representing the millis since Epoch
// Arg 2 is a timezome. Eg: "Europe/London"
// Arg 3 is an int relating to the formatting of the returned string
// Needs the time package. Obviously.

func getFormattedTimeFromEpochMillis(z int64, zone string, style int) string {
    var x string
    secondsSinceEpoch := z / 1000
    unixTime := time.Unix(secondsSinceEpoch, 0)
    timeZoneLocation, err := time.LoadLocation(zone)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error loading timezone:", err)
    }

    timeInZone := unixTime.In(timeZoneLocation)

    switch style {
        case 1:
            timeInZoneStyleOne := timeInZone.Format("Mon Jan 2 15:04:05")
            //Mon Aug 14 13:36:02
            return timeInZoneStyleOne
        case 2:
            timeInZoneStyleTwo := timeInZone.Format("02-01-2006 15:04:05")
            //14-08-2017 13:36:02
            return timeInZoneStyleTwo
        case 3:
            timeInZoneStyleThree := timeInZone.Format("2006-02-01 15:04:05")
            //2017-14-08 13:36:02
            return timeInZoneStyleThree
    }
    return x
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse unix timestamp in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987131/how-to-parse-unix-timestamp-in-golang)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than converting this to a string, you'll want to convert it to a `time.Time` and from there to a string. You can use the handy `Unix` method to get a `Time` object back for that time stamp.

```
import "time"
import "fmt"

t := time.Unix(0, 1502712864232)
fmt.Println(t.Format("02/01/2006, 15:04:05"))
```

Edit: added format to the println - note, testing your unix stamp in go playground, that value is neither nano seconds nor seconds, in both cases the time value produced is way off of what it should be. The code above still demonstrates the basic idea of what you want to do but it seems an additional step is necessary or the sample `int64` you gave just does not correspond to the string you provided.

relevant docs:

https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

Comment: Thank you! Turns out that what I thought was UnixNano is actually Epoch Millis. I made a helper function to convert epoch millis to a couple of different formatted strings and return the required one.

Comment: @user3202399 np! please accept the answer if you found it helpful.